# Retrieving email from Facebook Login in ASP.NET MVC throwing null exception

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oauth, facebook-login

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC application. In my application, I need to provide Faccebook Login service to user. Besides, I need retrieve the user email from Facebook and store in the database.

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and ASP.NET MVC5. My Facebook login method is working fine. But when I retrieve email from Facebook, it is giving me null exception. My externalLoginCallback method is below:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
        {

var result = await AuthenticationManager.AuthenticateAsync(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
            if (result == null || result.Identity == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login");
            }

            var idClaim = result.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
            if (idClaim == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login");
            }

            var login = new UserLoginInfo(idClaim.Issuer, idClaim.Value);

            var name = result.Identity.Name == null ? "" : result.Identity.Name.Replace(" ", "");

            //retrieving email from facebook here
            var externalIdentity = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetExternalIdentityAsync(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
            var emailClaim = externalIdentity.Result.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Email);
            var email = emailClaim.Value;//this line is throwing null exception


.
.
.
}
```

I commented where error throw in my code.

This is how I configured Facebook in Startup.Auth.cs

```
var facebookAuthenticationOptions = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions()
{
    AppId = "x",
    AppSecret = "y"
};
facebookAuthenticationOptions.Scope.Add("email");
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebookAuthenticationOptions);
```

I also tried like this:

```
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(new FacebookAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AppId = "x",
                AppSecret = "y",
                Scope = { "email" },
                Provider = new FacebookAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    OnAuthenticated = context =>
                    {
                        context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("FacebookAccessToken", context.AccessToken));
                        return Task.FromResult(true);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Both are not working. What is wrong with my code and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
    var facebookAuthenticationOptions = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions()
    {
        AppId = "xxxxxxx",
        AppSecret = "xxxxxx",
        BackchannelHttpHandler = new FacebookBackChannelHandler(),
        UserInformationEndpoint = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/me?fields=id,name,email,first_name,last_name,location"
    };
```

and then define this class:

```
public class FacebookBackChannelHandler : HttpClientHandler
{
    protected override async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (!request.RequestUri.AbsolutePath.Contains("/oauth"))
        {
            request.RequestUri = new Uri(request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri.Replace("?access_token", "&access_token"));
        }

        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        return response;
    }
}
```

finally, you can get email (and first_name,last_name,location)  by doing the following in "ExternalLoginCallback" method in account controller:

```
 [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
        {
            var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
            if (loginInfo == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("LoginRegister");
            }

            // GET MAIL AND NAME
            var email = loginInfo.ExternalIdentity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Email).Value;
            var name= loginInfo.ExternalIdentity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Name).Value;
```

Comment: what namespace do i need to have as I cant find loginInfo.ExternalIdentity

Comment: var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
This code is for ASP.Net MVC apps with Identity.
AuthenticationManager is part of Owin: (HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication)